# How make custom activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, configuration, custom-activity

I need to create a custom activity for Journey that must take the dataextension in input and associate to each a code (taken from an external API) and make a post call to an external server with [{id_utente_DE: code}, {id_utente_DE: code}, ...].
I created a small program with laravel, I think the problem is related to the file config.json or customActivity.js because anyway I can view the application in iframe and make the various scripts I have in js but the moment of validation I return the error "A custom activity or entry source failed validation. Check to ensure that the activity or entry source publishes to a valid endpoint".

This is my config.json

```
    {
  "workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
  "metaData": {
    "icon": "logo.png",
    "category": "message"
  },
  "type": "REST",
  "lang": {
    "en-US": {
      "name": "My Custom Activity",
      "description": "My Custom Activity"
    }
  },
  "arguments": {
    "execute": {
      "inArguments": [],
      "outArguments": [
        {
          "result": ""
        }
      ],
      "url": "https://www.my-domainlaravel.com/journeybuilder/execute",
      "body": "",
      "header": "",
      "useJwt": true,
      "timeout": 10000,
      "retryCount": 5,
      "retryDelay": 5000,
      "concurrentRequests": 3
    }
  },
  "configurationArguments": {
    "applicationExtensionKey": "my activity key",
    "save": {
      "url": "https://www.my-domainlaravel.com/journeybuilder/save",
      "body": "",
      "header": "",
      "useJwt": true
    },
    "publish": {
      "url": "https://www.my-domainlaravel.com/journeybuilder/publish",
      "body": "",
      "header": "",
      "useJwt": true
    },
    "validate": {
      "url": "https://www.my-domainlaravel.com/journeybuilder/validate",
      "body": "",
      "header": "",
      "useJwt": true
    },
    "stop": {
      "url": "https://www.my-domainlaravel.com/journeybuilder/stop",
      "body": "",
      "header": "",
      "useJwt": true
    }
  },
  "wizardSteps": [
    {
      "label": "Select object & assign code",
      "key": "step1"
    }
  ],
  "userInterfaces": {
    "configModal": {
      "height": 200,
      "width": 300,
      "fullscreen": true
    }
  },
  "schema": {
    "arguments": {
      "execute": {
        "inArguments": [
        ],
        "outArguments": [
          {
            "result": {
              "dataType": "anyType",
              "direction": "out",
              "access": "visible"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my customActivity.js

```
define([
    'postmonger'
], function (
    Postmonger
) {
    'use strict';

    var connection = new Postmonger.Session();
    var authTokens = {};
    var payload = {};
    $(window).ready(onRender);

    connection.on('initActivity', initialize);
    connection.on('requestedTokens', onGetTokens);
    connection.on('requestedEndpoints', onGetEndpoints);
    connection.on('requestedInteraction', onRequestedInteraction);
    connection.on('requestedTriggerEventDefinition', onRequestedTriggerEventDefinition);
    connection.on('requestedDataSources', onRequestedDataSources);

    connection.on('clickedNext', save);
   
    function onRender() {
        // JB will respond the first time 'ready' is called with 'initActivity'
        connection.trigger('ready');

        connection.trigger('requestTokens');
        connection.trigger('requestEndpoints');
        connection.trigger('requestInteraction');
        connection.trigger('requestTriggerEventDefinition');
        connection.trigger('requestDataSources');  

    }

    function onRequestedDataSources(dataSources){
        console.log('*** requestedDataSources ***');
        console.log(dataSources);
    }

    function onRequestedInteraction (interaction) {    
        console.log('*** requestedInteraction ***');
        console.log(interaction);
     }

     function onRequestedTriggerEventDefinition(eventDefinitionModel) {
        console.log('*** requestedTriggerEventDefinition ***');
        console.log(eventDefinitionModel);
    }

    function initialize(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data) {
            payload = data;
        }
        
        var hasInArguments = Boolean(
            payload['arguments'] &&
            payload['arguments'].execute &&
            payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments &&
            payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments.length > 0
        );

        var inArguments = hasInArguments ? payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments : {};

        console.log(inArguments);

        $.each(inArguments, function (index, inArgument) {
            $.each(inArgument, function (key, val) {
                
              
            });
        });

        connection.trigger('updateButton', {
            button: 'next',
            text: 'done',
            visible: true
        });
    }

    function onGetTokens(tokens) {
        console.log(tokens);
        authTokens = tokens;
    }

    function onGetEndpoints(endpoints) {
        console.log(endpoints);
    }

    function save() {
        var postcardURLValue = $('#postcard-url').val();
        var postcardTextValue = $('#postcard-text').val();

        payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
            "tokens": authTokens
        }];
        
        payload['metaData'].isConfigured = true;

        console.log(payload);
        connection.trigger('updateActivity', payload);
    }


});
```